# Runtime error 91 initializing arrays

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortLoggingEntrys()

    Dim entrys As entrys
    entrys.initialize (ActiveDocument.Tables.Count)
    Dim tableIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
      If InStr(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i), "text over table") Then
        'Check if table is in next 3 paragraphs
        For j = i To (i + 3)
            If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(j).Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                tableIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
                entrys.add DateValue(Left(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i), 10)), ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndex + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
     End If
    Next
End Sub
```

In class module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim mdate() As Date
Dim mtable() As Table
Dim index As Integer

Public Sub initialize(arraySize As Integer)
    ReDim mdate(arraySize)
    ReDim mtable(arraySize)
    index = 1
End Sub

Public Function getDate(ByVal ix As Integer) As Date
    Set getDate = mdate(ix)
End Function

Public Function getTable(ByVal ix As Integer) As Table
    Set getTable = mtable(ix)
End Function

Sub add(ByVal dat As Date, ByVal tabl As Table)
    mdate(index) = dat
    mtable(index) = tabl
    index = index + 1
End Sub
```

This is my first VBA script made in word. I get runtime error 91. In debugging mode i found out that the error occurs in the initialize procedure. Is it even possible to jump into the class module in debugging mode? I couldn't figure out how to jump into the procedure. Also i don't know why the error occurs. Google could not help me, hope you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `DIM` your variable of type `entrys`, you must set it to a new instance.

```
Dim entrys As entrys
Set entrys = New entrys
```